# Зависает GUI при DataBinding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток, господа!

Не могу решить проблему. Гугл не спасает.

Имею контрол, который кидаю на окно. В контроле весь код. В нем есть:

- ListBox
- TextBox
- FlowDocumentScrollViewer

Что делаю:
при загрузке контрола (в конструкторе) загружаю данные в свойство. CollectionViewSource привязано к этому свойству, далее группировка и сортировка. ListBox привязан, собственно, к CollectionViewSource.

Также произвожу поиск по ListBox с помощью TextBox и по переключению вкладки (по определенному параметру). И при смене SelectedItem передаю документ в FlowDocumentScrollViewer (с ним пока все нормально).

При любом из перечисленных действий - зависание 1-5 сек. Больше всего раздражает зависание при вводе в TextBox.

CollectionViewSource в контроле:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!--Declaire CollectionView-->
    <converters:FirstLetterConverter x:Key="FLConverter" />
    <converters:PlantToFlowDocumentConverter x:Key="PTFDConverter"/>
    <CollectionViewSource 
        x:Key="plantsView"
        Source="{Binding Plants, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ContentViewer}}}"
        Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"
        >

        <!--Grouping-->
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FLConverter}"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>

        <!--Sorting-->
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupingHeader">
        <Border 
            BorderBrush="#FFBABABA" 
            BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" 
            Margin="15,0,19,0"
            >
            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding Name}" 
                Foreground="#FFBABABA"
                />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

TextBox и ListBox

```
<TextBox 
            x:Name="searchTextBox"
            Margin="12"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Tag="Поиск"
            SelectionBrush="#FF55974D"
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            Style="{DynamicResource SearchTextBoxStyle}"
            Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            />
            <ListBox 
            x:Name="plantsListBox"
            Style="{DynamicResource TelegramListBoxStyle}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TelegramListBoxItemStyle}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=plantsView}}" 
            ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GroupingHeader}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="-5,0,-9,0"
            >
                <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=GroupingHeader}" />
                </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            </ListBox>
```

Конструктор:

```
public ContentViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        tabControl.Loaded += delegate
        {
            var tmp = tabControl.Template;
            var chk = (CheckBox)tmp.FindName("PART_CheckBox", tabControl);
            chk.Click += delegate
            {
                if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    Plants = OriginalCollection.Where(x => x.IsFavorite == true).ToList<Plant>();
                }
            };
        };
        Test();
    }
private void Test()
    {
        OriginalCollection = TestAdapter.GetData();
    }
```

Свойства:

```
private string _searchText = "";
    private List<Plant> _plants;
    private List<Plant> _originalCollection;

    public List<Plant> OriginalCollection
    {
        get { return _originalCollection; }
        set
        {
            _originalCollection = value;
            Plants = _originalCollection;
            OnPropertyChanged("Plants");
        }
    }


    public List<Plant> Plants
    {
        get
        {
            return _plants;
        }
        set
        {
            _plants = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Plants");
        }
    }

    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return _searchText; }
        set
        {
            _searchText = value;
            ((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["plantsView"]).View.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Фильтр (поиск)

```
private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        Plant item = e.Item as Plant;
        if (item.Name.ToUpper().Contains(_searchText.ToUpper()))
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (item.LatinName.ToUpper().Contains(_searchText.ToUpper()))
            {
                e.Accepted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Фильтр по значению:

```
private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var i = (sender as TabControl).SelectedIndex;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            Plants = OriginalCollection;
        }
        else
        {
            Plants = OriginalCollection.Where(x => x.IsFavorite == true).ToList<Plant>();
        }
    }
```

**UPD:**

Оказалось вешает GUI группировка в CollectionViewSource.